What is the best way to make Bitcoin Core recognize and sign transaction for custom descriptor?
The problem is that I have a custom witness script and I want Bitcoin Core to be able to sign transactions for that script.
Initially, I wanted to create a new standard address and use its key for signing, but this way bitcoin core can't catch up on the same public key it already knows. This issue: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/27336
So, now I want to use the private key of the current wallet with the hd-path.
But it requires strange manipulations like:

listdescriptors
Take random xpriv
Add this xpriv with some special hd-path to new descriptor
Import this descriptor
Then I can sign

I wonder is there a better way?
Descriptor for an example:
wsh(or_d(pk(<key bitcoin core should know>),and_v(v:pk(<another pk>),older(timelock))))
